# Best way to draw text with OpenGL and Cocoa?

Tags: cocoa, opengl

Does anyone know an easy way to draw arbitrary text in a Cocoa NSOpenGLView? I have a couple of constraints.

- The text on screen may change from frame to frame (for example, a framerate display in the corner)
- I would like to be able to select any font installed on the system at any size

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you taken a look at the [Cocoa OpenGL sample code](http://developer.apple.com/samplecode/CocoaGL/index.html)? It includes "a texture class for strings, showing how to use an NSImage to write a string into and then texture from for high quality font rendering."